# Android: retrieving an extra from intent in service?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

So I'm starting a service with a `putExtra` integer value that I want to pass along:

```
        Intent i = new Intent(context, clickService.class); 
        i.putExtra("numClicks", thisNumClicks); 
        context.startService(i);
```

And this starts the service. The question is how do I retrieve this value back whilst in the service? Here's what I tried that I remember using in a previous project (from an activity):

```
int result = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("numClicks");
```

However `getIntent()` is not defined for services I guess? What do I use then?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docs for [Context.startService(Intent service)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29)

> Every call to this method will result in a corresponding call to the target service's onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) method, with the intent given here.

So basically just use the Intent passed to `onStartCommand(...)`.